# Scale data to -1 to 1

Tags: python, pandas, scale

I have rows of data containing numbers in the range of "-finite to finite". I want to transform this number to the range of "-1 to 1" as it shows polarity. I would like to enter the result into a new column inside the same dataframe. Here's a sample of my data...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'reviewId': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
    'score': [-1, -5, 0, 3, 38]})
```

Comment: How do you scale *infinite* range into [-1, 1]? Mathematically, scaling infinite range to a finite one means each actual number simply becomes 0.

Comment: I made a change to my question. What I meant is "-finite to finite", but there is no range for the number.

Comment: Is this range predefined or is it inferred as (min to max) of the scores?

Comment: As min to max score

Comment: In that case ScottC's answer should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def normalize(x, newRange=(0, 1)): 
    xmin, xmax = np.min(x), np.max(x) 
    norm = (x - xmin)/(xmax - xmin) 
    if newRange == (0, 1):
        return(norm) 
    elif newRange != (0, 1):
        return norm * (newRange[1] - newRange[0]) + newRange[0] 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'reviewId': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
    'score': [-1, -5, 0, 3, 38]})

polarity = normalize(df.score.array, newRange=(-1,1))

df["polarity"] = polarity
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) from **sklearn.preprocessing** to transform to a specific range:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'reviewId': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
    'score': [-1, -5, 0, 3, 38]})

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
df['polarity'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['score']])

print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
  reviewId  score  polarity
0       01     -1 -0.813953
1       02     -5 -1.000000
2       03      0 -0.767442
3       04      3 -0.627907
4       05     38  1.000000
```

Comment: Prefer import `minmax_scale` function if the OP doesn't need to keep the `scaler` variable: `minmax_scale(df['score'], feature_range=(-1, 1))`. In fact it doesn't matter because the function calls `MinMaxScaler`. lol

Comment: Yes - was not sure if there were other columns that needed to be transformed - but good point.